# changing cism: Stereotype rdf:resource when exporting RDFS File

Tags: uml, rdf, enterprise-architect, rdfs, stereotype

I'm using schema composer Tool of EA with which I generate RDFS-Augmented files?

The person that uses these Files needs following:

```
cims:stereotype rdf:resource="http://iec.ch/TC57/NonStandard/UML#enumeration"/
```

I`ve tried creating my own stereotype using all available enumeration Stereotypes available in EA, but I always get the following:

```
cims:stereotype rdf:resource="http://langdale.com.au/2005/UML#enumeration"/;
```

Can anyone please explain to me what the difference is, and how I can change this?

**More Detail**

In EA you can create UML-Class diagrams which than can be exported with the build-in tool called schema composer to rdfs files.
These rdfs files are than used by someone else to automatically generate source-code from.
When modeling classes in EA they can have Types (for example "class") but they can also have stereotypes, my understanding is that stereotypes are there to extend the semantics of standard UML-Specification, so for example the type can be a class with stereotype «enumeration» which makes it known to the program as enum-type

[image]

now when you export this as rdfs-augmented File, as you can see the resource for the enumeration Stereotype is

```
"http://langdale.com.au/2005/UML#enumeration"/
```

the Person that uses these Files needs the UML-Elements to have following as the resource:

```
cims:stereotype rdf:resource="http://iec.ch/TC57/NonStandard/UML#
```

How can I achieve this?

Also I don't understand what the meaning of this "resource" is. UML is as far as I know standardised

Schema-Composer screenshot:
[image]

Comment: You'll need to add a lot more details before anyone will be able to reproduce your problem and possibly offer a solution.

Comment: @GeertBellekens I hope it is more understandable now ?

Comment: «enumeration» is not a stereotype biut a keyword

Comment: What selections do you make in the Schema composer? Can you add printscreens of that as well?

Comment: @GeertBellekens added, the Model used is CGMES v3

Comment: Just tried it myself with the same result. It pretty much looks like this is a hardcoded reference in EA. You can either update the xml file yourself, or write your own export. It might help if you send a bug report to Sparx, but don't expect a fix soon.